# Node.js How can I check if a word I selected is included

Tags: node.js

In Node.js I want to check if a string has 0...9(So all digits) followed by m,d,w,y but I don't know how. I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick_

```
\d[mdwy]
```

For more digits

```
\d+[mdwy]
```